# Error 404 files not found using response.sendfile()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

My /blog and /post trigger many 404 not found errors in the browser's console which can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HcGJ.png) **even though blog.html and post.html both work if I open it from my file explorer! (My scripts and css work)**

My api endpoints at /blog and /post give me these errors so none of the scripts for blog.html or post.html run. Note that the rest of my restful api works just fine.

Posts.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "css/style.css" type="text/css"> </link>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet"> </link>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jq/jq-datatables-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jq/jq1-12-4.js"></script>
</head>


<body width="100%" class="body">
  <div class = "PostPane">
    <form method = "post" action="/postEntry">
      Title: <input type="text" name="Title" value="Test"><br>
      Month: <input type="text" name="Month" value="August"><br>
      Year: <input type="text" name="Year" value="2017"><br>
      Paragraph: <input type="text" name="Paragraph" value="Today I added a post method."><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </div>

  <div class = "DeletePane">
    <form method = "post" action="/deleteEntry">
      Num: <input type="number" name="Num" value = "9"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </div>

<p>

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Blog.html:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href = "css/style.css" type="text/css"> </link>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet"> </link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
getEntriesArray ();
</script>
<div id="div1">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Node:

```
app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/post.html'));
});

app.get('/blog', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/blog.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the directory is not correct. So, it could not load the resource.
You can try to put them onto the same folder Or try to use some relative path like this:

```
<img src="picture.jpg"> : picture.jpg is located in the same folder as the current page 

<img src="images/picture.jpg"> : picture.jpg is located in the images folder located in the current folder

<img src="/images/picture.jpg"> : picture.jpg is located in the images folder located at the root of the current web

<img src="../picture.jpg"> : picture.jpg is located in the folder one level up from the current folder
```

Comment: I think it seems right according to my structure here: http://imgur.com/a/MNX5E It is working with my post.html file already. Also I added an edit in my post. When I hover over the files in the console, I get something like localhost:3000/css/style.css. Not sure if that's right

Comment: you might need to use the relative path: ../picture.jpg . This will get the directory bases on the current folder no matter what the url prior such as localhost:3000 or whatever else

Comment: By current folder, do you mean my node server.js file? I tried something like public/css/style.css for that case, but it still cannot locate it. I also tried making them relative to the html files as well, but that does not work either.

Comment: Also, my paths are fine when I open blog.html (the scripts run and the css runs), but it does not work when I visit my api endpoint at /blog

Comment: I guess that another problem with api endpoint. You might try to remove public before blog.html.
app.get('/blog', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'blog.html'));
});